# how to stop animating symbol at end of polyline?

Tags: typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I'm using basic animation example from [google-maps-docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-animate).

```js
function initMap(): void {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement,
    {
      center: { lat: 20.291, lng: 153.027 },
      zoom: 6,
      mapTypeId: "terrain",
    }
  );

  // Define the symbol, using one of the predefined paths ('CIRCLE')
  // supplied by the Google Maps JavaScript API.
  const lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 8,
    strokeColor: "#393",
  };

  // Create the polyline and add the symbol to it via the 'icons' property.
  const line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [
      { lat: 22.291, lng: 153.027 },
      { lat: 18.291, lng: 153.027 },
    ],
    icons: [
      {
        icon: lineSymbol,
        offset: "100%",
      },
    ],
    map: map,
  });

  animateCircle(line);
}


function animateCircle(line: google.maps.Polyline) {
  let count = 0;

  const icons = line.get("icons");
  window.setInterval(() => {
    count = (count + 1) % 200;
    icons[0].offset = count / 2 + "%";
    line.set("icons", icons);
  }, 60);
}
```

How do I stop animation at `2nd point` of polyline i.e `last point` and show marker at that point? As you can see in the doc the animation keeps repeating again again surely because of interval but I want to add `clearInterval` the moment my icon offset is at `last point`

I tried following:

```js
const stopAni = ref<number | undefined>();
function animateCircle(line: google.maps.Polyline) {
  let count = 0;

  const icons = line.get("icons");
  stopAni.value = window.setInterval(() => { // setting interval to variable
    count = (count + 1) % 200;
    icons[0].offset = count / 2 + "%";
    line.set("icons", icons);
  }, 60);

// I want to clearInterval at last point but i don't know where to add that?
//clearInterval(stopAni.value)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `clearInterval` with the `intervalID` when the count is equal to the maximum value (199):

```
if (count >= 199)
  window.clearTimeout(intervalHandler);
```

full function that animates once:

```
function animateCircle(line) {
  let count = 0;

  let intervalHandler = window.setInterval(() => {
    count = (count + 1) % 200;

    const icons = line.get("icons");

    icons[0].offset = count / 2 + "%";
    console.log("count="+count+" offset="+icons[0].offset);
    line.set("icons", icons);
    if (count >= 199)
        window.clearTimeout(intervalHandler);
   
  }, 20);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/c1jmdw04/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example adds an animated symbol to a polyline.
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: 20.291,
      lng: 153.027
    },
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: "terrain",
  });
  // Define the symbol, using one of the predefined paths ('CIRCLE')
  // supplied by the Google Maps JavaScript API.
  const lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale: 8,
    strokeColor: "#393",
  };
  // Create the polyline and add the symbol to it via the 'icons' property.
  const line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [{
        lat: 22.291,
        lng: 153.027
      },
      {
        lat: 18.291,
        lng: 153.027
      },
    ],
    icons: [{
      icon: lineSymbol,
      offset: "100%",
    }, ],
    map: map,
  });

  animateCircle(line);
}

// Use the DOM setInterval() function to change the offset of the symbol
// at fixed intervals, stop at the end.
function animateCircle(line) {
  let count = 0;

  let intervalHandler = window.setInterval(() => {
    count = (count + 1) % 200;

    const icons = line.get("icons");

    icons[0].offset = count / 2 + "%";
    line.set("icons", icons);
    if (count >= 199)
      window.clearTimeout(intervalHandler);

  }, 20);
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Animating Symbols</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```